# How to set clear UIWebView Background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to set the clear background of web view, but i could not found anything for this    issue, so please help me, so How will i remove gradient background and make UIWebview transparent?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this snippet code with your web view

myWebView.opaque = NO;
[myWebView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Comment: oh.. i knew it...i will try.

Answer (score 0):

To make UIWebView Background transparent you may use

```
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

If you also want to remove shadows create Category for UIWebView:

**UIWebView+ShadowRemoval.m**

```
#import "UIWebView+ShadowRemoval.h"

@implementation UIWebView (ShadowRemoval)

-(void)removeShadows
{
    for(UIView *view in [self subviews] ) {
      if( [view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]] ) {
         for( UIView *innerView in [view subviews] ) {
            if( [innerView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] ) {
                innerView.hidden = YES;
            }
        }
     }
  }
}

@end
```